# error on pushing to git on own server

Tags: git, git-push

at company we get setup own server with git.
we decided that each user will have own password to do this.
when I try to push I'm getting error:

> remote: fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/var/dev/xsl/hub/.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
>   error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
>   To own_server:/var/dev/xsl/hub
>    ! [remote rejected] current -> current (unpacker error)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'marcin@own_server:/var/dev/xsl/hub'

I change permissions on all files and folder to user/group what we are assigned, setup 777 too, but still this not fixed my problem. Any idea how to fix this? what's could be wrong.

Comment: I believe you're using gogs. It's probably because misconfigured permissions for folders. Can be solved with chown, I guess.

Comment: I try this. i try chown to all folders, also setup 777 on all folders but still getting this error

Comment: Will this fix it: `git config --bool core.bare true`

Comment: not, this not help :(